# SQL Server: User does not have permission to perform this action. (Read works)

Tags: sql-server, iis

After reinstalling `IIS` I can't log in. Any page has `Insert` or `Update` command, the page fails with error saying `User does not have permission to perform this action`

Select command works fine. I can edit table data using SSMS or Visual Web Developer but I can't modify or write through web site.
I'm using windows authentication.

Could you tell me which user's permission needs to be changed? 
As far as I can tell, everyone is reader, owner and writer.
I have `IUSER` -full control on file level and `NT AUTHORITY\IUSR` has full control on database level.

Comment: Does the account have any denies added to it?  The deny will override any grants...

Comment: I checked denies but yes, all unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling `IIS` might have messed up the mappings on the integrated accounts.

Try

`EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Report'`

If it reports orphaned users

`EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix', 'user', 'login', 'password'`

Where the last three parameters are for the broken account.

Need to be the admin and you need to use the database question.

Just a guess, but it's worked for similar issues for me in the past.

If there's aren't any then logging on as IUSer... might tell you something, or impersonating them.

Comment: Thank you for your hlep! I have no user showed up in the report.

Comment: what do I need to reinstall in order to fix this? sql server?

Comment: No Idea. This is a track it down thing. Start by making sure teh machine with IIS on can log onto sql server as the account IIS is ruuning as. Go from there.

Comment: I end up reinstalling everything from scratch. The tricky part was that I had to uninstall Windows Process Activation Service first. Otherwise it kept same IIS settings and it didn't work.

Comment: May be should migrate this then. Definitely not a coding issue.